# Start of activity not working Java

Tags: java, android

Hello i have 2 activities in android, and i want to go from one activity to another using a button.
 The main activity is:

```
public class AppActivity extends Activity
{
Button button; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {  

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, App2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

}

}
```

And it works just fine, but then i have the second activity that is supposed to call the first activity but does nothing:

```
public class App2Activity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button button, button_n1, button_n2, button_n3, button_n4, button_n5, button_n6, button_n7, button_n8, button_n9, button_n0, button_clear, button_div, button_mult, button_mais, button_menos, button_igual, button_pt;

EditText textcalc;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);
    textcalc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textcalc);
    Float num1, num2, total;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); 
    button_n0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_n0);
    button_n1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_n1);
    button_n2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_n2);
    button_n3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_n3);
    button_n4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_n4);
    button_n5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_n5);
    button_n6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_n6);
    button_n7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_n7);
    button_n8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_n8);
    button_n9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_n9);
    button_clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_clear);
    button_mult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_mult);
    button_div = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_div);
    button_mais = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_mais);
    button_menos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_menos);
    button_igual = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_igual);
    button_pt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_pt);

    // set a listener
    button_div.setOnClickListener(this);
    button_mult.setOnClickListener(this);
    button_mais.setOnClickListener(this);
    button_menos.setOnClickListener(this);
    button_clear.setOnClickListener(this);
    button_igual.setOnClickListener(this);
    button_pt.setOnClickListener(this);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    button_n0.setOnClickListener(this);
    button_n1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button_n2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button_n3.setOnClickListener(this);
    button_n4.setOnClickListener(this);
    button_n5.setOnClickListener(this);
    button_n6.setOnClickListener(this);
    button_n7.setOnClickListener(this);
    button_n8.setOnClickListener(this);
    button_n9.setOnClickListener(this);



}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String texto;
    texto = textcalc.getText().toString();
    Boolean numeros_existem = texto.endsWith("0") || texto.endsWith("1") || texto.endsWith("2") || texto.endsWith("3") || texto.endsWith("4") || texto.endsWith("5") || texto.endsWith("6") || texto.endsWith("7") || texto.endsWith("8") || texto.endsWith("9");

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button://não está a funcionar
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(App2Activity.this, AppActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent2);//vai começar a activity que é definida no 2ºparametro de intent
            break;
        //many more cases...

    }
}

}
```

Does someone has a clue why it doen't work?

---

SOLVED

It seems i was seaching for something that didn't exit. I changed the case to:

```
switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button2://this is the correct id
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(App2Activity.this, AppActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent2);//vai começar a activity que é definida no 2ºparametro de intent
            break;
        //many more cases...

    }
```

Comment: Doesnt work means??? any error???

Comment: @Nambari - no, not a duplicate.  The issue at your link was that the code was not within an (an inner class of) the Activity class whose instance it was attempting to use as a context, but in this case it is actually within the Activity class itself, not even in an inner class!

Comment: I mean, that the button does nothing. From activity2 it does not call the main activity.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: My mistake, I overlooked that part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intent and start activity code are fine.

Rather, your problem is that you are testing to see if the identity of your clicked view matches "R.id.button".  Yet, you have not set your activity class to be the on click listener of any view with that ID, so your the code that would start a new activity will never run.

Change your case statement to check for a match with one or more of the views that you have actually set your activity to be the listener for (or set it to be one for R.id.button), and it will work.

Comment: How can i possibly do that? Thanks!

Comment: Either include R.id.button in the views you are setting the listener for at the top of your activity, or include one of the views you did set a listener for in your case statement.  Not sure how that could not be clear, unless you are trying to adapt code you found somewhere without yet having a sense of what it does.

Comment: Anyways the error was another. I was searching for something that does not exist. button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); I had to put in case R.id.button2. Thanks for trying to help anyway!

Comment: That is **exactly** the problem I was pointing out to you - you were trying to match R.id.button for which you had never set this code as the listener, and needed to either set it as such or match one of the buttons you had set it to listen for.