# Button an event when clicked and a different one when pressed

Tags: java, android

I'm doing a calculator for fun, the code is in this post: 
[Start of activity not working Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682211/start-of-activity-not-working-java)

I have many buttons in my calculator, and one of them is a button that i want to use to clear the last charater of text in the textbox when i click and when i press it for more that x seconds i want it to clear all the text.

I've searched for many posts and i learned that the OnTouch method using handler is good for things that are being pressed, but how can i implement both things for my button?

Thanks in advance for the answers!

UPDATE

I used the Onclick listener and OnLongClick listener and it works exactly as i want!

Comment: clear last character of textview onclick of button... and clear all text onlongclick of button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want to set a View.OnClickListener, and a View.OnLongClickListener, like so:

```
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String s = mEditText.getText().toString();
            if (s != null && s.length() > 0) {
                mEditText.setText(s.substring(0, s.length()-1));
            }
        }
    });
    mButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            mEditText.setText("");
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
    Button myClearButton;

    //After doing myClearButton = findViewById(int id) or other methods of getting your button call this method:

    setClearButtonClickListeners(){
    myClearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    clearLastChar();
                }
            });

    myClearButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                    clearAllChars();
                    return true;
                }
            });
}
```

Just implement the clearLastChar() and clearAllChars() methods;

Answer (score 1):

```
clearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                         clear();

           Toast.makeText(HomeSafeActivity.this, "Normal Press", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        });


clearButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(HomeSafeActivity.this, "Long preess", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    yourEditText.setText("");
                return true;
            }
        });



 public void clear(){

    Editable editableText = yourEditText.getEditableText();
                int length = editableText.length();
                if (length > 0) {
                    editableText.delete(length - 1, length);
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //
        }
    });
btn.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    //
                    return true;
                }
            });
```